# How to get the max number in all sliding windows of an array?

Tags: java, arrays

Given an array of numbers and a sliding window size, how to get the maximal numbers in all sliding windows?

For example, if the input array is {2, 3, 4, 2, 6, 2, 5, 1} and the size of sliding windows is 3, the output of maximums are {4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 5}. The size of the sliding window is a variable passed to you.

A sliding window is basically a subarray of the original array that starts at a particular index. For instance, at index 0, with size 3, it's the first 3 elements. At index 1, with size 3, it's the 2nd, 3rd and 4th element.

How would you solve this in Java or any other programming language? Or pseudocode, if you so desire.

(Note: This is NOT a homework question, just a question I found on a site that I have my own solution to but want to compare it with others, I'll post my solution below afterwards too)

Comment: *I'll post my solution below afterwards too* I guess this is not how this site works. Probably you want to try it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `" I'll post my solution below afterwards too"` -- I'll just wait for your solution. I'm curious what a "sliding window" is and what its size means.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm waiting too

Comment: The question doesn't seem to make sense...I would help if you could explain what the question is bro.

Comment: The sliding windows comprise a sequence of subarrays of length n (n=3 here). So the target is an array of length l-n+1, containing the maxima of 0..2, 1..3, etc. Perfectly reasonable question if you ask me.

Comment: @MohammadS. given the array A of size N and the sliding window X, you start taking values from A[0] to A[X-1] and get the max element of this sub array, then do the same for A[1] to A[X], A[2], A[X+1]... until get to A[N-1-X] to A[N-1], you get the idea.

Comment: I wrote some simple and quick pseudo code, but it's too late to post now lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in `O(N*Log(W))`, where `N` is the size of your array, and `W` is the size of the sliding window.

Use a binary tree to store the first `W` numbers. For the following `N-W` steps, get the `max` value from the tree for your output, add the element at the current position `i` to the tree, and remove the element at `i-W` from the tree. These operations are all `O(Log(W))`, for the overall timing of `O(N*Log(W))`:

```
int[] data = new int[] {2, 3, 4, 2, 6, 2, 5, 1};
int W = 3;
TreeMap<Integer,Integer> counts = new TreeMap<Integer,Integer>();
for (int i = 0 ; i != W ; i++) {
    if (counts.containsKey(data[i])) {
        counts.put(data[i], counts.get(data[i])+1);
    } else {
        counts.put(data[i], 1);
    }
}
for (int i = W ; i != data.length ; i++) {
    Integer max = counts.lastKey();
    System.out.println(max);
    int tmp = counts.get(data[i-W])-1;
    if (tmp != 0) {
        counts.put(data[i-W], tmp);
    } else {
        counts.remove(data[i-W]);
    }
    if (counts.containsKey(data[i])) {
        counts.put(data[i], counts.get(data[i])+1);
    } else {
        counts.put(data[i], 1);
    }
}
System.out.println(counts.lastKey());
```

[Demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/FV7C7I).

Comment: Does it matter if you store the index of the elements in the heap (along with the values)? Then when you get the max, you need to check the index. If it's NOT in the sliding window, you remove it, and try and get the max again, do this until the max number's index is in the sliding window.

Comment: Also, I presume if this was Java, you'd use a PriorityQueue data structure?

Comment: @HenleyChiu Since at each step after the initial `W` you add exactly one element and also remove exactly one element, you know that the tree/heap always contains exactly `W` elements; hence you know for sure that the max is inside the sliding window.

Comment: @HenleyChiu Yes, `PriorityQueue<T>` sounds like a good candidate for this data structure. Of course if you'd like to stay within primitive data types, you can roll your own heap backed by an array of primitives.

Comment: Removing that one element from the heap => is this still O(Log W) if that element is a random location in the heap?

Comment: @HenleyChiu Ah, you're right, only removing the `max` (or `min` in minheap) is fast; removing an arbitrary item is `O(W)`, so heap would not work, only a tree. Finding `max` is no longer `O(1)`, but then insertion and deletion are `O(W)` anyway, so there is no loss in asymptotic time complexity.

Comment: Wouldn't using a heap still work? When you delete the i-wth element, you replace the deleted element with the last element, and perform a sift-down to ensure that it ends up in the proper place. Which should take O(log w). Am I mistaken?

Comment: @HenleyChiu Re-heapifying is not a problem, it's finding the element to replace that would be linear (i.e. `O(W)`).

Comment: You take the last element to replace it, which should be constant time, no?

Comment: @HenleyChiu The last element from the window is at an arbitrary spot in the heap. You need to search for it, which I believe is linear.

Comment: Then why is DeleteMin of a heap's running time usually acknowledged as O(log w)? It also involves deleting the last element and putting it in the top, and percolating it down. I believe most heap implementations keep track of the size of the heap, and can get the last element in constant time?

Comment: @HenleyChiu DeleteMin knows where the `min` is (it's at the end). The algorithm wouldn't be deleting `min` all the time: you will be deleting the value that corresponds to the element at `array[i-W]`, which may be positioned at an arbitrary place.

Comment: Hmm.. let me put it another way: Suppose you use a heap, and ONLY delete the min (not the number that is in i-w). You would need to check if the min is outside of the window too. If it's not you just run DeleteMin once. If it yes, you'd be running DeleteMin another time - at most 2 times (only 1 number can fall outside of the window in each iteration). Therefore even if you use a heap, it'd still be O(n* logW). What is the fault in this reasoning?

Comment: @HenleyChiu If I delete `min`, the number at `i-W` would satay in the array for longer than it needs to, and may show up as the max incorrectly. Please see the edit to see how one can implement this.

Comment: Oops you're right! I forgot to mention that I wanted the heap to store an object with the value AND the index of that value. When we do a delete min, we have to check the index to ensure it's in the window. If not, we delete min two times. I guess your way is simpler.

Comment: @HenleyChiu Even if you store the index along with the value, you may end up removing more than 2 items till you find the correct value. I think the code I relatively simple - it would be even shorter had it not be for the awkward way Java uses maps.

Comment: Yep, your solution is cleaner and more elegant. I pasted my version below, as promised :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't mind pseudocode/other langs, how about this (in Python):

```
l = [2, 3, 4, 2, 6, 2, 5, 1]
result = [max(l[i:i+3]) for i in range(len(l)-2)]
```

Comment: The question is tagged as Java and not as python nor as language-agnostic. By the way, I'm curious about the performance of this short code.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza O(NW) where N is input length and W is window size.

Answer (score 0):

I always start with the naive algorithm if I'm trying to solve something like this. What's wrong with scanning the array window by window? Well, when you see what's not great about that (you're repeating the same comparisons over and over), you can start to look for other approaches.

One approach is suggested by visualizing the initial array as a mountain range: find the highest peak. Nothing's taller than that, so that's the max for the windows around it. Now you can proceed recursively. There are probably other, better approaches.